# Ambiguous [textbuffer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I'm talking about [textbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textbuffer).

Current status:

- Carried by **16 questions**.

  - **9** of them uses it as a component in GTK
  - **6** of them uses it as a (computationally) generic buffer that's intended to store text
  - [One last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225871/5958455) that I don't know whatever its author thinks this tag is for
- First apprearance: [Nov 23, 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4251658/revisions)
- Has neither a wiki nor an excerpt

As it currently is, slightly more than a half of the questions uses it as a GTK component. Since GTK TextBuffer cannot have another name, and there's no need for a tag for a general buffer whose only relationship with `textbuffer` is its intention (whatever a buffer stores makes no difference to the computer), I suggest removing this tag from the 7 irrelevant questions, renaming it to [gtk-textbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtk-textbuffer) and making this a synonym to that, as well as adding necessary excerpt to direct further askers away from adding this tag unless their question is about GTK TextBuffer.

In case the SO community thinks this tag is used too infrequently, burninating it is also a fine solution. I agree that a frequency of less than 2 Q per year is absolutely too low.

---

Side note: These three questions ([A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225871/5958455), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20610336/5958455), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20604377/5958455)) seem to have some internal relationship as they contain very similar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, there was 1 new question about text buffer again related to GTK.

4 out of the 6 questions which you mention were being used as "generic buffer that's intended to store text", were all by one user who was writing a text buffer class. They seem to be separate questions, so I just removed the tag from it (it seemed a bit suspicious, and I dug a bit, but that's mod related and not tag related).

Among the 2 other questions, I closed and deleted one, and retagged the other.

Finally I renamed the tag as [gtk-textbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtk-textbuffer). The next step is to add a tag wiki.